# Lodash - How to ignore zero while using _.orderBy ascending on number field?

Tags: node.js, lodash

User list -

```
const users = [
    {
        name: "user1",
        active: true,
        limit: 5
    },
    {
        name: "user2",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user3",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user4",
        active: true,
        limit: 2
    },
    {
        name: "user5",
        active: true,
        limit: 0
    }
];
```

Here the users with lower value of `limit` must appear first(ascending order of limit) and users not having `limit` must be sorted alphabetically. But users having `limit = 0` should be in the latter sort(alphabetical sort).

The code for sorting using lodash libarary in Node.js-

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(users, ["limit", "name"], ["asc", "asc"]);
```

Output using the above code -

```
[
    {
        name: "user5",
        active: true,
        limit: 0
    },
    {
        name: "user4",
        active: true,
        limit: 2
    },
    {
       name: "user1",
       active: true,
       limit: 5
    },

    {
        name: "user2",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user3",
        active: true
    }
]
```

But the expected output is -

```
[
    {
        name: "user4",
        active: true,
        limit: 2
    },
    {
       name: "user1",
       active: true,
       limit: 5
    },
    {
        name: "user2",
        active: true 
    },
    {
        name: "user3",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user5",
        active: true,
        limit: 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your users' limit at a string instead of a number (`'0'`, `'2'`, `'5'`), the order is the same.

But you can provide a function instead of directly a name, so you can hack the thing:

```js
const sortedUsers = _.orderBy(
  users,
  [
    (a) => {
      return a.limit ? a.limit : undefined;
    },
    'name'
  ],
  ["asc", "asc"]
);
```

This way, `0` would end up being considered - for ordering purposes only - the same way as `undefined`, which put the `0`-valued objects at the end of your order.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need lodash for this simple work. If you still want to use lodash, Please use the same sort function in lodash argument.

```js
const users = [
    {
        name: "user1",
        active: true,
        limit: 5
    },
    {
        name: "user2",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user3",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "user4",
        active: true,
        limit: 2
    },
    {
        name: "user5",
        active: true,
        limit: 0
    }
];

const sortedData = users.sort(({limit = 0}, {limit:yLimit = 0} )=> {
    return yLimit - limit
})
console.log(sortedData)
```